# Extending jQuery autopager

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a project which requires the use of [jquery-autopager](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-autopager/). I need a way to query some status information about the pager, so I've modified the libraries' code to include the isLoading and hasMore functions. They work fine.

```
--- a/jquery.autopager-1.0.0.js 2009-10-13 16:42:41.000000000 +0000
+++ b/jquery.autopager-1.0.0.js 2013-04-28 00:02:33.000000000 +0000
@@ -98,6 +98,14 @@
        options.start(currentHash(), nextHash());
            $.get(nextUrl, insertContent);
            return this;
+       },
+
+       isLoading: function() {
+           return active;
+       },
+
+       hasMore: function() {
+           return (nextUrl ? true : false);
        }

    });
```

My question is : is there any way I could, from my own code, merge these new functions into autopager, so that I can avoid modifying an external library?

I've tried this, but the variable I'm trying to refer to doesn't seem available in this context :

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.autopager, {
  isLoading: function() {
    return active;
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post more code? .extend should work, but the devil is in the details.

Comment: Here is the complete source code for the autopager library, it's just one file, 171 lines long : https://code.google.com/p/jquery-autopager/source/browse/trunk/jquery.autopager.js